# How to check if the inputted data exist in database

Tags: java, jdbc

I would like to know if what am I lacking here, I can't compare the 'id' from the Textfield to the data from the database.

For example:

> > If TextField1 == to the data in the database.
>
> Output: Swept by GSW.

```
Connection con = connect.getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM item_list WHERE id = ?";
        
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;
        int id;
                
        try{
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            
            while(rs.next()){
              id = rs.getInt("id");
              
              if(Integer.parseInt(TF[0].getText()) == id){
                System.out.println(id);
                }
            }
        }catch(SQLException exc){
            System.out.println("Not Found!");
        }
```

Kindly Check the Image Output.
I attached the image file below.

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZR43.png)

[image]

Comment: Well, you are doing that in a catch, print the exception to find out the problem. I see in PhpMyAdmin that the field is called `Id` and you use `id` in the query. I bet on a field unknown "id"  excepetion

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `PreapredStatements` unless you `id` literally equals `?`

Comment: Please try to log exception stack trace , it will help you to understand the problem properly

Answer (score 1):

Here are some mistake I see

- You use a parameter in the query, `"SELECT * FROM item_list WHERE id = ?";`so use a `PreparedStatement`
- Set the parameter to that `PreparedStatement ps = connection.preparedStatement(query);` with `ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(TF[0].getText()));`
- Don't catch the exception without logging it, here your query as a syntax error but you don't know it.
- careful with uppercase in the database field name "Id"

This might not be everything ...

And of course, now that you get only the row with that ID, you can simply check if there is at least one row return to validate that it exists.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, you need to log a stack trace of an exception that is thrown. At least you can use `exc.printStackTrace()` in your `catch` section.
2. Second, your issue is that you declared a parameter for your SQL query, but you have not put any value to it.

```
    PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM item_list WHERE id = ?");
    p.setString(1, TF[0].getText() ); //VALUE_FROM_YOUR_TEXT_INPUT
```

4. You don't need to iterate over all result set to check if a user with such id exists. You can just check that result set is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `intValue()` for `Integer` object obvious if your object is not null

```
 while(rs.next()){
      id = rs.getInt("id");

      if(Integer.parseInt(TF[0].getText()).intValue() == id){
           System.out.println(id);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the value of the id parameter in the statement.  Not familiar with Java but in C# it would be something like 
`statement.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)`

Answer (score 0):

Thank You guys! I've been trying and reading all your suggestions, and I've found and debugged it. Thanks to the one said that I need to check what message I can get in the catch.

Appreciated all your help.

```
Connection con = connect.getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM item_list";

        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;
        int id;

        try{
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()){
              id = rs.getInt("id");

              if(Integer.parseInt(TF[0].getText()) == id){
                System.out.println(id);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FOUND!");
                }
              else{
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Found!");
              }
            }
        }catch(SQLException exc){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exc.getMessage());

        }
```

[ID Found!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdTet.png)